# Drop compulsive http requests same url, same IP in Apache tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ddos

I want to drop http request done to the same url from the same ip inside the same second. That means, its a guy violently pressing F5 or a bot screwing up my server.

Do anyone knows any lib for java to avoid this or should I develop a Map in memory checking who is killing the server ?

Answer (score 1):

think about modsecurity with a apache providing a reverse proxy

http://www.modsecurity.org/

you can also add some network layer qos rules, if certain ip's or networks are hammering your server, then rate limit them. :-).

Comment: I know this mod, but I need something just for Tomcat, I'm not using apache+tomcat, just tomcat.